# Add listview item to the top of a Android Pull to refresh ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am using the RefreshableListView (Pull to refresh) from [here](https://github.com/woozzu/RefreshableListView) .But I am using a Custom ListAdapter and not the ArrayAdapter. It working all fine but the only issue is that it is adding new items to the bottom of the list while **I want new items to be displayed on top.** .
I have referred to a lot of articles on the net addressing similar issues but have not found a solution for my issue. It will be great if anybody could point out where I am going wrong.

Here are the code snippets:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist, mItems);

    mListView = (RefreshableListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Callback to refresh the list
    mListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(RefreshableListView listView) {
            ivFooter.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            new NewDataTask().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

and the AsyncTask

```
private class NewDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        String retVal = myArrayList.get(i);
        if (i < myArrayList.size() - 1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mItems.add(0, result);
        mListView.completeRefreshing();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

and Custom Adapter class

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }


    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
        }
        String quote = myArrayList.get(position);
        if (quote != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvQuote);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivPicture);
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(quote);
            }
            if (iv != null) {
//Setting image
}
return v;
}
```

'mItems' is the original list with one item and I am adding 'myArrayList' to it. 
Like I said its working fine but adding elements (on refresh) one by one at the bottom ..while I want the new elements to be added on top. 
Any inputs would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `String quote = myArrayList.get(position);` with `String quote = RefreshableListViewActivity.this.mItems.get(position);` and it works as expected.
Thanks to @Dante for helping me out.